# Concatenate string and int

Tags: python, string, list

I want to concatenate integer and string value, where integer is in a 2D list and string is in a 1D list.

```
['VDM', 'MDM', 'OM']
```

The above mentions list is my string list.

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

The above mentioned list is my integer list.

I have tried this code:

```
for i in range(numAttr):
    for j in range(5):
        abc=[[attr[i]+counts[i][j]]]
print(abc)
```

Here numAttr is the number of element in the first 1D list. and second 2D list is a static list i.e. for any dataset the 2D list will not change.

The above code showing the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I want a list output which looks like this:

```
[['VDM:1','VDM:2','VDM:3','VDM:4','VDM:5'],['MDM:1','MDM:2','MDM:3','MDM:4','MDM:5'],['OM:1','OM:2','OM:3','OM:4','OM:5']]
```

Comment: As asked, this question is too broad; it does not have a proper [mre]. The question in the title seems to ask only about doing the concatenation for a single string-integer pair, which is properly scoped; but the post asks for a way to get this result repeated across an entire nested list - how to repeat the process for each element of the nested list is a *separate question*. As such, this is not a good signpost for the canonical duplicate (it would be not be a good question even if the duplicate did not exist). Voting for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nested list comprehension below:

```
>>> l = ['VDM', 'MDM', 'OM']
>>> l2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> [[a + ':' + str(b) for b in c] for a,c in zip(l, l2)]
[['VDM:1', 'VDM:2', 'VDM:3', 'VDM:4', 'VDM:5'], ['MDM:1', 'MDM:2', 'MDM:3', 'MDM:4', 'MDM:5'], ['OM:1', 'OM:2', 'OM:3', 'OM:4', 'OM:5']]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> l = ['VDM', 'MDM', 'OM']
>>> l2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> [['{}:{}'.format(a, b) for b in c] for a,c in zip(l, l2)]
[['VDM:1', 'VDM:2', 'VDM:3', 'VDM:4', 'VDM:5'], ['MDM:1', 'MDM:2', 'MDM:3', 'MDM:4', 'MDM:5'], ['OM:1', 'OM:2', 'OM:3', 'OM:4', 'OM:5']]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> l = ['VDM', 'MDM', 'OM']
>>> l2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> [['%s:%s' % (a, b) for b in c] for a,c in zip(l, l2)]
[['VDM:1', 'VDM:2', 'VDM:3', 'VDM:4', 'VDM:5'], ['MDM:1', 'MDM:2', 'MDM:3', 'MDM:4', 'MDM:5'], ['OM:1', 'OM:2', 'OM:3', 'OM:4', 'OM:5']]
>>>
```

Or f-strings (version >= 3.6):

```
>>> l = ['VDM', 'MDM', 'OM']
>>> l2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> [[f'{a}:{b}' for b in c] for a,c in zip(l, l2)]
[['VDM:1', 'VDM:2', 'VDM:3', 'VDM:4', 'VDM:5'], ['MDM:1', 'MDM:2', 'MDM:3', 'MDM:4', 'MDM:5'], ['OM:1', 'OM:2', 'OM:3', 'OM:4', 'OM:5']]
>>>
```

Comment: I prefer f-strings :D

Comment: @PatrickArtner Me too, just afraid that the OP will say, "it gives an error", since python < 3.6 doesn't work with f-strings, anyways will edit

Comment: @PatrickArtner Haha i like how you format your deleted answer :P

Comment: If not f-strings, then just: `[['{}:{}'.format(a, b)]...]` is fine...

Comment: @JonClements Oh yeah

Answer (score -1):

Change the line `abc=[[attr[i]+counts[i][j]]]` to `abc=[[attr[i]+':'+str(counts[i][j])]]`